# Find SQL Server 2008 database connections and how to kill them

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to find current SQL Server database connections and how can I know which connection is connecting with which database, as I have multiple databases on my SQL Server.

And how can I kill any one of these connections?

Is it possible that I can perform all these tasks using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Do you want to kill all connections to a specific database? Run `USE YourDatabase;ALTER YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;ALTER YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_who`

```
kill spid;
```

for killing a connection/proccess..(You ll find spid in the first column of the previous sp).

There is also a column called "dbname" which refers the database.

Comment: Thanks Helgato, it helps me in finding the current connections to my database.

Comment: i have total 10 physical systems connected to my database, but in connections list its showing 42 connections connected with my server, then i checked in details, one system is having multiple connections with different spid each connection.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that i understand what you ask. ,maybe this helps , but you have to be more specific..

Use a group by to the following table query

```
DECLARE @Table SPTABLE(
        SPID INT,
        Status VARCHAR(MAX),
        LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX),
        HostName VARCHAR(MAX),
        BlkBy VARCHAR(MAX),
        DBName VARCHAR(MAX),
        Command VARCHAR(MAX),
        CPUTime INT,
        DiskIO INT,
        LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX),
        ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX),
        SPID_1 INT,
        REQUESTID INT
)

INSERT INTO @SPTABLE EXEC sp_who2

SELECT  *
FROM    @SPTABLE
where DbName is not null
```